# Intersection of Focal Chords of an Ellipse

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

[This is the original Question. My Question is more of like a starting point for this question. And believe me this is not a homework question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGtaJ.png)

Let $\mathbb{E}$ be an ellipse with focii $S$ and $S'$. Let $AB$ and $CD$ be 2 focal chords of the ellipse (Both pass through $S$). Let $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $K$. Prove that $K$ lies on the directrix corresponding to focus $S$.

Comment: nirav this is not a homework site. pls edit the question and include what you have tried and done. see this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Comment: @JitendraSingh from where have you copy pasted the comment ? I see it quite often and wish to use it to educate new users

Comment: @omjoglekar Click on flag then on needs improvement then on a community specific reason and then the full line is present. You can copy that and paste that in comments

Comment: @nirav Start with a sketch. Then tell where the problem is. Did you note down vote score 3?

Comment: $A,B,C,D$ are points  on the ellipse.

Comment: Ok so me replying to the comments - 
1) This is not a homework problem! Some friend sent me another problem and while sketching that problem I found this property which I was unable to prove (Ill add that problem later)
2) idk like I guess all the terms I used in the Question are quite standard
5) what is a sketch? Should I add a diagram?

Comment: @Nirav24 Isn't the answer to the duplicate question fine for you?

Comment: Yes its fine. Thanks a lot!